# Pygments style less accurate than Ace editor theme

Tags: syntax-highlighting, ace-editor, pygments

The joined image shows a same syntax highlighted (LaTeX) code in two blocks codes, both with the same [`Dracula`](https://github.com/dracula) style/theme:

- the first one with [`Pygments`](https://pygments.org/),
- the second one with [`Ace Editor`](https://ace.c9.io/).

[image]

As one can notice, the `Pygments` syntax highlighting is less accurate than the `Ace Editor` one. Is it possible to improve the `Pygments` syntax highlighting style in order to make it as accurate as the `Ace Editor` one (and as close as possible)?

Comment: You can use ace as a syntax highlighter instead of pygments https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/static-highlighter.html

Comment: @auser I created such an `.html` file but it looks ugly. Because of `<script src="kitchen-sink/require.js"></script>` and the like, it isn't self-contained, is it?

Comment: @auser BTW, the `.html` I created is the one that can be seen here: https://ace.c9.io/demo/static-highlighter.html.

Comment: @auser Oh, I see now: https://fenixrepo.fao.org/cdn/js/alpaca/1.5.18/dist/lib/ace-builds/demo/static-highlighter.html